# Pantheios: create a new log file when too large

Tags: c++, logging, file-io, pantheios

I want to make it so when Pantheios has written 1GB of data to a file, it will stop filling that file and create a new one and use that. I believe this is called Log rolling and I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

To be clear I'm not asking for anyone to code this for me but I just don't know where to find this information or if its even called Log rolling.

Comment: What you need is called _log rotation_

Comment: The results aren't much better when I try to look for pantheios log rotation but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing what creating my own back end. I basically made a function that will write things to a the current file if(currentfileSize < rolloverSize) else create a new file. It was easier to do then I thought, so if you need to do log rolling / log rotation then I recommend writing your own back-end.

Comment: Can you give your code to look upon? I have been searching but all are in vain.